# How to add ". - N." before issue number in bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, bibliographystyle

What I want:

S. Advani, J. Torok und J. Lee // General solutions for pistonlike displacement ofcompressible fluids in porous media. Journal of energy resources technology. – 1985.– V. 107. **- N.** 4. – P. 523–526.

What I have:

S. Advani, J. Torok und J. Lee // General solutions for pistonlike displacement ofcompressible fluids in porous media. Journal of energy resources technology. – 1985.– V. 107. 4. – P. 523–526.

How can I add dot, dash and N (". - N.") before issue number?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage[ 
    backend=biber, 
    style=numeric
]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} 
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{% 
bibencoding=utf8, 
bibwarn=true, 
sortlocale=de_DE, 
isbn=false, 
url=false, 
doi=false, 
eprint=false, 
clearlang=true, 
maxbibnames=99, 
firstinits=true, 
sorting=none, 
} 
%\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\space //\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{{#1}} 
%\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{{#1}}% number of a journal
%\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkfirstpage[{\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]}]{#1}} 
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
   page = {{}{}}, 
   pages = {{}{}}, 
} 
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\adddot \addspace \text{--} \addspace}%точка-тире после издателя
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\adddot\space \text{--}\space \text{V.} }% точка-тире после года
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}% 
 \setunit{\addcolon\space }%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{eid}%
}
\newbibmacro*{issue+date}{% убираем скобочки вокруг года
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\adddot \space \addperiod \space \text{--}\space  \text{P.}}% точка тире перед номером страницы



 
\addbibresource{mybib.bib} 
\begin{document} 

Text~

\cite{advani1985general}

\begingroup
\let\itshape\upshape
\printbibliography 
\end{document}

@article{advani1985general,
  title={General solutions for pistonlike displacement of compressible fluids in porous media},
  author={Advani, SH and Torok, JS and Lee, JK},
  journal={Journal of energy resources technology},
  volume={107},
  number={4},
  pages={523--526},
  year={1985},
  publisher={American Society of Mechanical Engineers}
}
```

Comment: Copy of my comment under your other recent question: This looks suspiciously as though you want a GOST bibliography. There is already a `biblatex` style for that: https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-gost. No need to code everything yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already declare a field format, just modify it accordingly:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{{--\addnbspace N.\addnbspace #1}}
```

Comment: Got it:) Thank you very much!